# React Native: Optimized SectionList does not rerender after scrollToLocation

Tags: react-native, expo

I built an alphabet scrubber that scrolls a SectionList. The SectionList is optimized through the use of getItemLayout. If I scrub over the alphabet, the scrolling happens as planned, but the SectionList does not rerender until I release my finger from the screen.

[See this expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@gersomvg/alphabet-scrubber-(snack))

Anyone ideas on how to solve this?

[image: Screenshot of example]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved it by going through the source code of PanResponder. PanResponder sets an interaction handle through the InteractionManager. You can access this handle through `this.panResponder.getInteractionHandle()` (undocumented feature), and then clear it everytime you scroll to a location in the SectionList:

```
if (this.panResponder.getInteractionHandle()) {
    InteractionManager.clearInteractionHandle(
        this.panResponder.getInteractionHandle()
    );
}
```

This will move the SectionList up in the queue for doing its visibility calculations and renders.

I advice to heavily optimize this by clearing the interaction handle as few times as possible, since the InteractionManager is used for performance reasons.

Comment: Nice solution! They clearly need to document this more. Glad to hear you solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

For the sectionList to update dynamically you need to place the data its using into State. This Expo example(done by someone else), is a good example:

https://snack.expo.io/Syy1bqKxW

His panResponder has all its data in state and on every "handlePanResponderMove" he calls setState() to update the position every time it moves. All in all, if your data is not in state, it will not update dynamically for you. Placing your data into state in React-Native is how it keeps track of your data changes dynamically.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Gersom. I would appreciate some feedback on my answer above. Trying to get more rep points. Let me know if you have questions! :)

Comment: SectionList should know that it should rerender, since its scrollToLocation method gets called. It works when you lift the finger of the screen and there is also no state change then. I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but I'm looking for a solution that hopefully works without a setState trick :)

Comment: @Gersom No problem. But State is not a trick its part of the React-Native framework.  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html - "For data that is going to change, we have to use state.". Your data is loading in as it scrolls. So when you pan, your data is changing. As per my link, you need to use State to track this.

Comment: Tried your solution, and it does not work ;) The reasoning behind SectionList deciding what items to render is not just being influenced by state changes of the parent component. Or at least not when a finger is touching the screen. I've also tried calling component.forceUpdate().

Comment: @Gersom Cool Sorry it didn't work! :) I have not worked with the panResponder component before so i am not sure how that works fully. It might only respond to touch release for some reason. Good luck with it! :)